# Defining preprocessor symbols in a FAKE MSBuild task

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, c-preprocessor, f#-fake

Is there a way to define a preprocessor symbol in an `MSBuild` task in FAKE?

For example, if my code has something like this in it:

```
#if LOCAL
private static string databaseUrl = "http://localhost/myDbFile.sqlite";
#else
private static string databaseUrl = "http://www.website.com/myPublicDbFile.sqlite";
#endif
```

Then I want to define the symbol `LOCAL` at build-time, in my F# build script.

Comment: I guess it depends on what type of build script you are using. You can either use the `/define` command line argument or the `DefineConstants` project property. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx

Comment: I'm using [FAKE](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/) as a build script engine. It has a few built-in MSBuild-related tasks, but none seem to have an option to use the `/define` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Ron Beyer (see comments) for pointing me in the right direction. The answer was indeed to use the `DefineConstants` project property. In a typical FAKE MSBuild task, this would look like this:

```
// Build a special version with the "SPECIAL" directive defined.
MSBuild
    null 
    "publish" 
    ([
        ("Configuration", "Release"); 
        ("Verbosity", "minimal");
        ("ProductName", "My Project (Special)");
        ("InstallUrl", "http://www.example.com/software/MyProjectSpecial/");
        ("DefineConstants", "SPECIAL")
    ])
    ["../MyProject/MyProject/MyProject.csproj"] 
        |> ignore
```

Comment: This is also related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003614/fake-how-to-define-msbuild-properties