# FAKE: How to define MSBuild properties?

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I want to switch from MSBuild to FAKE. In my MSBuild script I create a Webdeploy package by invoking MSBuild with the properties DeployOnBuild=True and DeployTarget=Package. This will trigger webdeploy to generate a deployment package while the build is running:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(ItemToBuild)"
         Targets="Build"
         Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);
                     Platform=$(Platform);
                     DeployOnBuild=True;
                     DeployTarget=Package;
                     OutFolder=$(OutFolder)" />
```

How can I do the same thing with FAKE? I've come this far:

```
Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    !! solutionFile
    |> MSBuildRelease binDir "Build"
    |> Log "Build-Output: "
)
```

How can I specify the required properties?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/31a93745b427da20308ee8c6f90710b57596956d/src/app/FakeLib/MSBuildHelper.fs#L509), you'll see that `MSBuildRelease` is just a shortcut for `MSBuild` proper with certain predefined properties. If you need to define other properties, besides "Configuration", you can just fall back to `MSBuild`:

```
Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    !! solutionFile
    |> MSBuild binDir "Build" 
         [ 
            "Configuration", "Release"
            "Platform", "AnyCPU"
            "DeployOnBuild", "True"
            "DeployTarget", "Package"
            "OutFolder", "/what/ever"
         ]
    |> Log "Build-Output: "
)
```