# Narrow down MSBuild verbosity to limit fake build output

Tags: msbuild, f#-fake

Any ideas how to limit the output generated by the MSBuild task in fake build?
I am not so much interested in seeing all compile info details as I am interested in seeing warning messages.

I started using StyleCop.Analyzers and if I get a single warning, it is hard to observe among all messages the build task is generating.

Here's how I have it now:

```
// Target Build Application
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
    MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build" appReferences
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
)
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34006757/180286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general helper function in the MSBuild helper is [`MSBuildHelper.build`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/MSBuildHelper.fs#L363). All other functions are specializations of it.

This function takes a `setParams` function, which follows a general FAKE pattern: takes default parameters structure and modifies it in some way. To set log verbosity, use the `MSBuildParameters.Verbosity` field:

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ -> 
    "Project.sln"
    |> MSBuildHelper.build (fun p ->
        { p with
             Properties = [ "OutputPath", buildDir ]
             Verbosity = Some Minimal
             Targets = [ "Build" ] } ) )
```

Alternatively, you can set the verbosity for the whole build by modifying the `MSBuildDefaults` structure:

```
MSBuildDefaults <- { MSBuildDefaults with Verbosity = Some Minimal }
```

This way, all MSBuild invocations will use minimal verbosity.

Comment: I've seen in the documentation that I can make use of MSBuildHelper.build and I understand that MSBuildRelease is a specialization.

I even tried to play with it, but got stuck on building the whole solution - I have project separation for application projects and test projects. That is why I prefer the building by *.csproj files approach.

The second part of your answer I like the most as it allowed to fix what I wanted with not making changes to my current solution. Thanks :)

Comment: The `build` function only takes one project (or solution), so you can't just build all of them in one go. Instead, you have to call `build` multiple times, iterating over the projects. This is exactly what the [next specialization up does](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/MSBuildHelper.fs#L424). I agree, there ought to be a middle specialization - one that takes multiple projects, but still allows to specify parameters. But there isn't.