# F# / FAKE - How to specify `--platform:x64` when invoking MSBuild

Tags: f#, 64-bit, f#-fake

I am very new to FAKE. I use the following code (based on the official FAKE example) to build some F# project:

```
Target.create "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
  [ p.buildTarget ]
    |> MSBuild.runRelease id buildDir "Build"
    |> Trace.logItems "AppBuild-Output: "
)
```

Everything is great except that it builds a 32-bit application, while I explicitly need a 64-bit one (with `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />`, of course) as otherwise it would not make a dent. This answer: [FAKE: How to define MSBuild properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003614/fake-how-to-define-msbuild-properties) seems to reference FAKE 4 but it looks that I have FAKE 5.

How can I tell FAKE 5 to build a 64-bit application? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set properties by supplying a `setParams` function other than `id` to `MSBuild.runRelease`:

```
Target.create "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
  [ p.buildTarget ]
    |> MSBuild.runRelease (fun p ->
        { p with Properties = [ "platform", "x64" ] } ) buildDir "Build"
    |> Trace.logItems "AppBuild-Output: "
```